# How to rename img files upon uploading/compressing using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to upload img-files using php, compress them, and rename them. I am stuck at the rename part. Can someone look at my code and tell me how I could achieve that?

this is my html form:

```
    <form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
      <input type="file" name="imagefile1" accept="image/*" capture="environment">
      <input type="submit" value='upload1' name='upload1'>
    </form>
```

this is my php code:

```
            if(isset($_POST['upload1'])){

            // Getting file name
            $filename = $_FILES['imagefile1']['name'];
            
            // Valid extension
            $valid_ext = array('png','jpeg','jpg');

            // Location
            $location = "uploads/".$filename;

            // file extension
            $file_extension = pathinfo($location, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);

            // Check extension
            if(in_array($file_extension,$valid_ext)){

                // Compress Image
                compressImage($_FILES['imagefile1']['tmp_name'],$location,20);

            }else{
                echo "Invalid file type.";
            }
            }


             // Compress image
            function compressImage($source, $destination, $quality) {
            
              $info = getimagesize($source);
            
             if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
               $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
            
             elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
               $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

             elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
              $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

                  imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the information you already retrieve to give your image a new name:

```
$filename = $_FILES['imagefile1']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$image_name = $yours_new_name.'.'.$ext;
```